# Фибоначчиева система счисления

Tags: c, алгоритм, вывод

Код вроде бы рабочий, но я нашел пока пару тестов, на котором он валится. При 4 должен выводить 100, при 4939952 10100000010100100010100000000010. Либо я где-то напутал с типом переменных, либо неправильный сам алгоритм, но это из области фантастики. Эксперты, помогите!
Собственно, сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long a,b, k, x, supercount=0, count=0;
    unsigned long sumc=0;
    a=0;
    b=1;
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    k=x;
    if (x==0){
        printf("0");
    }
        for(;x > 0;){
            while ((k >= 0) && (a <= x-b)){
                a=a+b;
                b=a-b;
                k=k-1;
                count++;
                printf("ct=%d\n", count);
            }
        x=x-a;
        sumc |= 1 << count-2;
        b=1;
        a=0;
        count=0;
        }
        printf("sumc=%lu\n", sumc);
    int r=sumc;
    while (r!=0){
        r /= 2;
        supercount++;
    }
    int arr[supercount];
    for (int q=0; q<supercount; q++){
        if (sumc!=0){
            arr[q]=sumc%2;
            sumc/=2;
        }
    }
    for (int i=supercount-1; i>=0; i--){
        printf ("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: На скорость задачи решаете?
  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733913/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Тем более вам уже ответили на английской версии. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865049/fibonacci-coding-by-the-zeckendorfs-theorem