# Фибоначчиева система счисления, ошибка вывода

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть код, который переводит целое число `x` в фиббоначиеву систему счисления по теореме Цекендорфа. Проблема заключается в том, что код работает не для всех вводимых значений.

*Пример:*

*`Ввод` -> `Вывод`


`3` -> `100`

`4` -> `101`

`7` -> `1010`

`100` -> `1000010100`*

Тем не менее, при вводе значения `34639092`, на выходе мы получаем `101000010100101000000000100010011010`, что является неверным ответом. *(см. теорему Цекендорфа)*

Правильным ответом в данном случае будет `101000010100101000000000100010010010`. Фактически, почти идентичный ответ, но здесь отсутствует единица в 4 позиции справа. При отладке кода можно заметить, что эта единица в неверном ответе появляться никаким образом не должна.

Не могу понять причину вывода неверного ответа для такого значения, подозреваю ошибку в коде.

Сам код, язык Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    unsigned long x = 0, res = 0, f = 0, bb = 0;
    long pos = -1;
    scanf("%lu", &x);

    for (f = 0; x > 0; f = 0, pos = -1) {
        for (int k = 1, n = 1; k < (x+1); n += k, k = n-k) {
            f = k;
            pos++;
        }

        if(pos > bb) bb = (pos - 1);
        x -= f;
        res |= 1 << (pos-1);
    }

    for (int i = bb; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(res & (1 << i)) printf("%d", 1);
        else printf("%d", 0);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: для наглядности, на Питоне алгоритм для [представления Цекендорфа](https://ideone.com/MBdW0Y)

Comment: @jfs не совсем понятно выражение `b = b` в 6 строке

Comment: `a, b = b, a+b` в Питоне означает `t=a; a=b; b=t+b`

Comment: @jfs понял, спасибо. Однако проблема заключается не в написании алгоритма, а в выявлении места, где в 4 бит справа устанавливается значение "1". Примечательно, что в первом цикле через логгирование можно проследить, что этот бит не затрагивается. То есть, выражение (pos - 1) никогда не возвращает значение "3" для сдвига, соответственно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865049/fibonacci-coding-by-the-zeckendorfs-theorem

Comment: @0andriy это мой тред, переведенный на английский, его я тоже читаю, но спасибо за ссылку на него, возможно кому-то поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема обнаружена и решена.

Строку

```
res |= 1 << (pos-1);
```

Нужно заменить на

```
res |= (unsigned long) 1 << (pos-1);
```

Аналогично со строкой

```
if(res & ((unsigned long) 1 << i)) printf("%d", 1);
```

Comment: `(unsigned long) 1` гораздо лучше смотрится как `1UL`, хотя, если тебе нужны 64-битные числа, то лучше `unsigned long long` и `1ULL`.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, полность согласен, спасибо за правку

Comment: Стоит явно упомянуть, что ошибка из-за того что int 32 битный на платформе, где баг проявляется, а пример в вопросе порождает больше бит (в представлении Цекендорфа). Как @Qwertiy заметил unsigned long может быть недостаточно (в переносимом коде), поэтому следует использовать тип, который гарантированно больше 32 бит (1ULL). Это также относится и к `res` типу. ¶ Независимо ещё можно посмотреть как себя код ведёт в районе `x` ~ `ULONG_MAX`.